# Keras Numerical and Categorical Features Embedding for RNNs

Tags: python, pandas, tensorflow, keras, recurrent-neural-network

I am trying, without success, to build a **simple Keras RNN** model that treats numerical and categorical features differently. The dataset I am using is a **Pandas Dataframe** in the following format:

```
| sequence_id |             cat_f1 |        cat_f2 |        num_f1 |        num_f2 |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|     seq1    |  [bread, grissini] |   [cat, dog]  |   [0.7, 0.1]  |   [0.1, 0.2]  |
|     seq2    | [pizza, mozzarella]| [lion, tiger] |   [0.2, 0.2]  |   [0.3, 0.9]  |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

The actual DataFrame' shape is **(1480, 3, 49)**, where 1480 is the number of samples, 3 is the length of the sequence (2 in the example), 49 is the total number of features (4 in the example).

It is important to note that the creation of the sequences is a personalized procedure which takes into account different factors and different columns. Thus, this procedure cannot be reprodecued in the Keras model and it must be done before initializing the model. All sequences have the same length.

I am currently feeding to my RNN numerical features. Thus, I first encode the strings to integer numbers (e.g. bread->0, grissini->1, ...), I convert the Pandas DataFrame to a Numpy array (1480x3x49) and then I create the model in the following way:

```
model = Sequential()
# window_size is 3, n_features is 49
model.add(Input(shape=(window_size, n_features)))
model.add(
    RNN(
        units=256,
        recurrent_dropout=0.1,
        return_sequences=False,
    )
)
model.add(Dropout(0.1))
model.add(
    Dense(
        units=128,
        activation="sigmoid",
    )
)
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Dense(n_classes, activation="softmax"))
```

However, I would like to **embed the categorical features** (cat_f1 and cat_f2 in the example) **and pass the numerical features** (num_f1 and num_f2 in the examples) **as they are.**

I have tried with `tf.feature_column.categorical_column_with_vocabulary_list` and `tf.feature_column.sequence_categorical_column_with_vocabulary_list` without success because the first does not seem to process multi-dimensional data and the second is experimental and works only with SparseTensor.

Answer (score 3):

I have found a solution. The best way is to switch from a sequential model to the **functional API**. This way, I can set multiple inputs, embed the categorical inputs and pass the numerical inputs as they are. The code is:

```
from tensorflow.keras import Input
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Embedding, concatenate

inputs_num = Input(shape=(window_size, features_num.shape[2]), name='numerical')
masked_num = Masking(mask_value=0.0)(inputs_num)

inputs_cat = [Input(shape=(window_size, ), name=e_col) for e_col in embed_cols]
inputs = [inputs_num]+inputs_cat

embeds_cat = [Embedding(v_size, 64, mask_zero=True)(i_cat) for v_size, i_cat in zip(vocab_size, inputs_cat)]

inputs_concat = concatenate([masked_num]+embeds_cat)
```

I attach the full model image, along with the shapes, hereafter:
[image]